# Order of evaluation of cases in Scala partial function

Tags: scala, partialfunction

Can I assume an order on the evaluation of cases of a partial function in Scala?

So for instance, given

```
protected val eval: PartialFunction[(TestPrimitive, Seq[Literal]), Boolean] = {
    case (L3IntLt, Seq(IntLit(x), IntLit(y))) => x < y
    case (L3IntLe, Seq(IntLit(x), IntLit(y))) => x <= y
    case (L3IntGe, Seq(IntLit(x), IntLit(y))) => x >= y
    case (L3IntGt, Seq(IntLit(x), IntLit(y))) => x > y
    case (L3Eq, Seq(x, y)) => x == y
    case (L3Ne, Seq(x, y)) => x != y
  }
```

If I could assume that cases are evaluated in order I can factor the code as:

```
protected val eval: PartialFunction[(TestPrimitive, Seq[Literal]), Boolean] = {
    case (L3Eq, Seq(x, y)) => x == y
    case (L3Ne, Seq(x, y)) => x != y
    case (arithp, Seq(IntLit(x), IntLit(y))) => arithp match{
      case L3IntLt => x < y
      case L3IntLe => x <= y
      case L3IntGe => x >= y
      case L3IntGt => x > y  
    }
  }
```

Is it a good programming practice to assume there is an order in the evaluation of the cases?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In [Programming in Scala](http://www.artima.com/pins1ed/) (First Edition), [chapter 15](http://www.artima.com/pins1ed/case-classes-and-pattern-matching.html), you'll find:

> A match expression is evaluated by trying each of the patterns in the order they are written. The first pattern that matches is selected . . .

Answer (score 1):

Yes, cases are evaluated top to bottom, first one to match wins. It is a fine practice as it is generally understood by scala programmers, and it's a very common pattern used by a lot of scala code.

For example, for non-exhaustive matches, it is common to specify a catch all:

```
x match {
  case "value1" => ...
  case "value2" => ...
  case other => ...
}
```

Clearly this is dependent on order, since if the catch-all case was at the beginning, it would catch everything.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the order of evaluation is one of the thing we need to do upfront anyway.. Also I would do the same refactor my code like you did!